# Filter on product listing using addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento-1.8, collection-filtering

I've been asked to help upgrading a Magento shop from version 1.5.1 to Magento 1.8.1
I'm not a Magento developer, but have much experience with PHP.

The previous developer added a way to filter products based on a custom attributes, width. There are 2 two input fields, `width-from` and `width-to`, and when the user input something in them and presses enter, it reloads the product listing page and adds them as GET paramters (`http://site.com../?width_from=...`).

Since there is no documentation of the solution, I've tried looking around to see where it is implemented. As far as I can tell, modifications have been made to `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php`, where the function `getProductCollection()`have been altered:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {
        $collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }
        if(!empty($_GET['width-from'])) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('width', array('gteq' => (int) $_GET['width-from']));
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['width-to'])) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('width', array('lteq' => (int) $_GET['width-to']));
        }

            //$collection->printlogquery(true);

    return $collection;
}
```

So, as you can see the previous developer used `addAttributetoFilter` to add the filter. However, I'm having problems moving this code to Magento 1.8.1. I've tried to add the following to `getProductCollection` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php`:

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {
        $collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }

    $collection->clear();

        if(!empty($_GET['width-from'])) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('width', array('gteq' => (int) $_GET['width-from']));
        }
        if(!empty($_GET['width-to'])) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('width', array('lteq' => (int) $_GET['width-to']));
        }

    $collection->load();    

           // $collection->printlogquery(true);

    return $collection;
}
```

Basically, I've added the calls to `addAtributetoFilter`, as well as called the `clear()`and `load()` method (just to check, doesn't seem to make a difference). However, when I input something in the filters it causes the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.width' in 'where clause'

Trace:
#0 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#4 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#5 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(808): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php(274): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 1000)
#8 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(1000)
#9 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(314): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#12 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme213/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(46): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/shop-r...')
#16 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/theme213/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(57): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/shop-r...')
#25 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#32 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /var/www/shop-reza.dk/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Actually the filtering works. If I in the file `app/design/frontend/default/theme213/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` as the first thing writes `<?php die(); ?>`, the execution stops before the problematic code. This means that the product listing is displayed (correct with the filters applied), but for example the layered navigation block is removed.

I suspect that the way this filtering is done is horrible wrong with respect to Magento development. Thus, if any of you have a better/preferred way to apply filters on the product listing page (based on some GET parameters), let me know!

Comment: Make sure the attribute you are filtering on has "Used in product listing" set to 'Yes'. Then reindex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, although not in the optimal way.

By tracing the SQL query actually executed by Magento, I noticed that the table it looked in was in `catalog_product_flat_1`. So, in `Configuration → Catalog → Product` I disabled `Use Flat Catalog Product` and then made a reindex.